# Postgres: Group by is extremely slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a 800 gb table. I have tried to create a minimal example to replicate things.
You can also create the same using.

```
create table test(id int, date timestamp without time zone);
insert into test  (select trunc(random() * 10000 + 1), NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days' from  generate_series(1, 1000000));
create index on test(id, date);
```

I have a table with the following schema.

```
                          Table "public.test"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer                     |           |          | 
 date   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "test_id_date_idx" btree (id, date)
```

I am trying to find the latest timestamp for each id using the following.

```
select id, max(date) from test group by id;
```

Following is the execution plan

```
 Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=14852.44..14952.25 rows=9981 width=12) (actual time=136.638..137.846 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Group Key: id
   Buffers: shared hit=5406
   ->  Gather  (cost=12656.62..14752.63 rows=19962 width=12) (actual time=125.804..130.419 rows=30000 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=5406
         ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=11656.62..11756.43 rows=9981 width=12) (actual time=120.528..121.882 rows=10000 loops=3)
               Group Key: id
               Buffers: shared hit=5406
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..9573.08 rows=416708 width=12) (actual time=0.015..31.523 rows=333367 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=5406
```

My first question is that why doesn't the query use an index? (since the index will already have everything sorted)

If I filter on `id`, the planner shows it started using an index. For example.

```
select id, max(date) from test where id in (1000 random ids) group by id;
```

Following is the query plan.

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..27941.65 rows=9981 width=12) (actual time=0.902..98.836 rows=947 loops=1)
   Group Key: id
   ->  Index Only Scan using test_id_date_idx on test  (cost=0.42..27342.16 rows=99936 width=12) (actual time=0.649..86.269 rows=95712 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{thousand random ids}'::integer[]))
         Heap Fetches: 95712
 Planning Time: 2.948 ms
 Execution Time: 98.961 ms
```

But this query is doing a lot of heap fetches. I don't understand why is this happening because if I get the max(date) for a particular id it is pretty fast and takes very low IO. Example

```
postgres=# explain analyze select max(date) from test where id = 3072;
                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=4.48..4.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.177..0.179 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..4.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.168..0.169 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using test_id_date_idx on test  (cost=0.42..406.42 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.165..0.166 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: ((id = 3072) AND (date IS NOT NULL))
                 Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning Time: 0.327 ms
 Execution Time: 0.241 ms
(8 rows)
```

I `ananlyzed` the table before any queries. All these numbers get amplified on my 800 gb table.

Comment: In what way do the numbers get amplified?  Is there just many more rows, or also many more groups?

Comment: Maybe you want a skip scan, which PostgreSQL doesn't yet implement directly but you can emulate it with a recursive CTE.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan

Comment: @jjanes, there are 1000 thousand times more rows. Anyways your suggestion to recheck if vacuum really happened worked for me. Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't disclose your PostgreSQL version, but it is probably an older one.

To avoid the heap fetches, `VACUUM` the table. Perhaps then PostgreSQL will choose an index-only scan. But since the table doesn't have more columns than the index, it might also prefer a sequential scan.

For a hash aggregate, the table doesn't have to be sorted.

Comment: my postgres version: `psql (13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-4.pgdg18.04+1), server 12.8`. Also I vacuumed the table, still same results. Since the data is already sorted why is there even a need to go to hash aggregates, also why are there so much heap scans in the later case?

Comment: After a `VACUUM`, there will be few heap fetches. Tables have no reliable ordering, and query execution cannot depend on such an ordering.

Comment: By data is already sorted, I meant the data is already sorted in the index.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you temporarily `SET enable_hashagg = off;` and force PostgreSQL to do a group aggregate, does it use the index? Is the cost lower? Is the performance better? Could you get rid of the heap fetches?

Comment: @satindersingh If there are still so many heap fetches even after a vacuum, then someone must be holding onto a snapshot which prevents vacuum from doing its job. close that, the vacuum again.

Comment: @jjanes, you were correct, my table wasn't getting vacuumed.

Comment: After vacuuming the table. The first group by (without the where clause) also got converted into index scans. Also index scans were not taking considerable IO this time.